# unset warranty bit

Tags: samsung, rooting, warranty

I recently installed Magdisk by patching the raw `boot.img`, unlocking the bootloader, and flashing the `boot.img` as boot. Now I have Magdisk. However, during the boot, 3 things happen:

1. `set warranty bit` appearing in the upper-right corner
2. bootloader unlocked warning - probably solveable by locking the bootloader while magdisk is still installed
3. warning at the top that it is not samsung official firmware

is there any way to undo these things? for example, the image showing the non-samsung firmware text could be replaced by a empty .png, and the warranty bit could be unset - it's just a single bit on my disk, right? i have a samsung galaxy a14(SM-A14R)